# Questions simply seeking ideas

Tags: discussion

[What kind of game (in Scratch) would require use of a list?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/154/what-kind-of-game-in-scratch-would-require-use-of-a-list)

It is clearly too broad, but finding great examples is also entirely central to what we do as educators.  How could a question like this be reworked to both help someone like @Scimonster find ideas for projects, but also garner "Good Subjective" answers?

To add to this, we already have a [lesson-ideas](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lesson-ideas) tag.

Comment: As a courtesy, when you discuss a specific question on meta, especially in private beta, could you leave a comment on the question?

Comment: Sure. Sorry about that! I'm relatively new to working with meta, and I hoped that tagging you with @ would show up on your top bar.  I'll add a note there for others who stop by the question as well.

Comment: Nope, @-tagging users doesn't work in posts, only in comments (and only in certain cases).

Comment: I've gathered :)  Again, apologies.  I intended to have you pinged... like I said, this is rather new to me.  I'll also leave notes in the future.

Comment: It's all fine now, so no worries. I know it can take a little while to get used to all the intricacies of SE.

Comment: @Scimonster I think this question, and other like it in the future, could be corrected by asking for decision criteria rather than available options. To aid that such questions needs to have more information, such as listed by Peter in his answer, and including some of the criteria the OP already has in mind, such as _something that can be done in an hour-long lesson_ already given. _What elements of a game created in Scratch will help elementary students understand 'lists'?_ Seems to be more defined and more useful to the site than a simple listing of possible games.

Answer (score 7):

While I like the idea of soliciting help for finding examples, I think this particular example would fall under the category of "too broad."

As I see it, this relates to our lesson plan review thread. It could just be as simple as providing more context; the question itself is not inherently problematic. I'd just want to know things like:

- Is the goal game design?
- Is the goal understanding lists?
- What is the experience level of students?
- What is the context for wanting to know this? Teacher-led demo?

The issue to me is precision. With more context and background, this kind of subjective question can lead more towards good than bad.

It'd be good to form a list of helpful information when we get questions like this one, so we say, "To improve your question, please provide X, Y, and Z..." as in student ability, classroom context, learning objective, etc. Determining the key elements to making a "good subjective" question for teaching examples is our challenge here in meta as we form this community.

Answer (score 2):

AS seen by the answers posted before it was closed, the question *is* too broad. Even if it was narrowed down as Peter suggests, it still is likely to generate answers that are either simply the name of a game, or a list of games. As such, in a general way, it's not a good fit for SE sites on any stripe. A better approach is probably to ask about the elements to look for in a game that will help you link to the desired concepts. I'm not saying that in this case using lists is not the best way to create the desired connection, but often when a list-generating question is asked it ends up being called an ["XY" problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/351780). The OP wants to do "X" (the issue) but asks about "Y" (the proposed solution. Questions do better, get more useful answers, when the objective, or problem, is presented directly.

Answer (score 1):

The goal, particularly in beta, should be to take these overly broad questions and edit them into something (probably narrower) which can be re-opened as a good example of the question. This can be a tricky thing to practice, and some questions are probably better left to be deleted, but this one for example seems worth rescuing. One approach that seems to work is to modify the question so that the best answer of the list is actually a good fit - interestingly, sometimes this actually results in a subsequent answer which is even better.

Comment: I agree in principle, but I am having trouble figuring out how to fix it.  It really feels like it's just missing too much information